# Run a command in background and exit

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to run a command silently via ssh and exit the shell, but the program should continue running.
I tried screen and nohup, but apparently with those it executes 3 processes instead of 1:

user:`/bin/bash ./[script]`
root: `sudo [commandInTheScript]`
root: `[commandInTheScript]`

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: The thing is that I want to run this command with the Workflow app (iOS), but the app waits until the command is finished, so it freezes 'forever'

Answer (score 1):

To run your process back ground, at end of the command you have to use `&`.
In your case, you have to run without session since you are planning to exit from `ssh` after execute the command, so you need `nohup`

```
nohup <command> &
```

Answer (score 0):

nohup < command > &

This makes your *command* runs on background and shows its PID

Answer (score 0):

How did you use nohup?

Eg. 
    **nohup ruby server.rb &**

Ampersand (&) is necessary to let command run in the background.