# Do I have to leave the terminal open while using the Parse Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, server

I have an AWS EC2 Instance running Ubuntu.

I've installed Parse Server on it and MongoDB. I noticed that whenever I close the terminal on my laptop, my android app cannot reach the server.

So my question is if I close the Java terminal window, leave the instance running on AWS, and still make usage on my Parse Server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221974/run-a-command-in-background-and-exit

Comment: @MarkB Thanks! Now the server runs in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the `nohup` command:

```
$ nohup parse-server --appId APP_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI DATABASE_URI &
```